# Why is my app crashing when it calls Google Maps class in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-maps

I am building an app and need to open the map after either a picture is taken from the camera or is selected from their images. It runs a python script to generate a random set of GPS coordinates, which I know is working fine as I have had it output the result to the screen and has done so correctly. Now, when I call the Google Maps class to open the map and display the generated coordinates, it gives an error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aggiemap/com.example.aggiemap.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

I am writing it in Kotlin. Here is the code from MainActivity. The map opened before but once I added the python script, it has stopped working and closes the app every time it gets to that point.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == pickImage) {
        imageUri = data?.data
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri)

        // PYTHON HERE
        val py = Python.getInstance()
        val pyobj = py.getModule("main")
        this.lat = pyobj.callAttr("runlat").toDouble()
        this.long = pyobj.callAttr("runlong").toDouble()

        /* Open the map after image has been received from user
     This will be changed later to instead call the external object recognition/pathfinding
     scripts and then pull up the map after those finish running
     */
        val intent = Intent(this, MapsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    if (dynamic) {
        // PYTHON HERE
        val py = Python.getInstance()
        val pyobj = py.getModule("main")
        this.lat = pyobj.callAttr("runlat").toDouble()
        this.long = pyobj.callAttr("runlong").toDouble()

        dynamic = false

        /* Open the map after image has been received from user
     This will be changed later to instead call the external object recognition/pathfinding
     scripts and then pull up the map after those finish running
     */
        val intent = Intent(this, MapsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

And here is the code from MapsActivity class

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.google_map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    // Add a marker at generated coordinate
    val location = LatLng(MainActivity().lat, MainActivity().long)
    val zoomLevel = (17.0).toFloat()
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Your Estimated Location"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location,zoomLevel))
}
```

}

Thank you in advance for any help. I have been stuck on this issue for days and can't figure out why it isn't working or what the error means.

Comment: The error's saying that somewhere in ``MapsActivity``, you have something that's meant to be a ``SupportMapFragment`` but it's actually null. And that's throwing an error, so the Activity can't start. Have a look at where you're using a ``SupportMapFragment`` in your code and make sure you're handling that potential null

Answer (score 1):

Here's your error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aggiemap/com.example.aggiemap.MapsActivity}:
 java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

`null cannot be cast to non-null type SupportMapFragment` means you're trying to cast something (using `as`) to the **non-null** type `SupportMapFragment`, but the thing you're casting is actually **null**, so the cast fails. Here's where you're doing that (the stacktrace tells you exactly which line number the error is on btw):

```
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.google_map) as SupportMapFragment
```

`findFragmentById` [will return null if there's no fragment with that ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int)) present in the `FragmentManager`. So you need to either cast to the nullable type (`SupportMapFragment?`) and handle the null, or ensure that fragment definitely exists before you make this call

Comment: Thank you for the help. I fixed the issue and appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

`onMapReady(...)` is called with `null` parameter.

Now, when you override that function `onMapReady` with non-null parameter `googleMap: GoogleMap`, Kotlin compiler automatically generates validation code that actually forcing the parameter to be non-null by throwing that exception you encountered if it's null.

Since this parameter can be null, you should mark it as nullable, then that validation code won't be generated - `googleMap: GoogleMap?` (also, you need to add handling in case it's null).

Full signature:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
    mMap = googleMap
    // Add a marker at generated coordinate
    val location = LatLng(MainActivity().lat, MainActivity().long)
    val zoomLevel = (17.0).toFloat()
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Your Estimated Location"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location,zoomLevel))
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I've definitely seen people with these kinds of null errors in Maps callbacks, but I think in this case it's that cast in ``onCreate`` - you get a different error wording for a null value that's not meant to be null (as opposed to a cast failure). And ``unable to start activity`` usually means it's failed during the setup phase - a callback would usually happen "later", after the Activity's started. Those are the clues pointing me in that direction, anyway!

Comment: You have a `unable to start a activity` `RuntimeException` that caused by `NullPointerExceptiin` - they simply catch the null pointer exception and throw another one in top of it. Feel free to post the full stack trace to be sure.